# Automating using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, automation, bugzilla

I have tried using the following script to automate bugzilla, everything is working properly but it is asking to give enter at one place, how I can pass enter?

My script:

```
cd /var/www/html/bugzilla
chmod +x checksetup.pl
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
./checksetup.pl --check-modules <<EOF
y
y
y
EOF
./checksetup.pl
```

Comment: An empty line should be enough assuming the program is reading from `stdin`

Comment: i have tried empty line but it is not taking

Comment: or use expect command.

Comment: Where is it getting stuck?  You are already running with a here doc; at what point does it wait for a hard return?

Comment: after last yes it is asking for Path to pg_config and I want to pass enter key.